# Changing next value breaking code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a system that allows a user to type in inputs and then a new one appears under it when filled in. The issue I am running into is I am attempting to add labels to the inputs and when I changed the code, it no longer adds new inputs.

The snippet is without the labels. [This is a Fiddle with my attempt at adding the labels](https://jsfiddle.net/xfbLskhn/2/).

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(function () {   
    var elems = $('.intro').on('input', function() {
        
        if ( this.value.trim().length > 2 ) {
          $(this).next('input').addClass('block');
        }

        
        $('#intro-button').toggle(
            elems.filter(function() {
             return this.value.trim() !== "";
            }).length === elems.length
        )
        
    });
});
```

```css
.intro {
 opacity: 0;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 margin: 40px auto;
 visability: hidden;
}
.intro:first-child {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
}
.block {
 display: block;
 visability: visible;
 opacity: 1;
   -webkit-animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
   -moz-animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
    animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
}
.next {
 display: none;
}
.button-center {
 margin: 40px auto;
 text-align: center;
}
#intro-button {
 display: none;
 padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="intro-info">
    <input id="name" type="text" class="intro">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="intro">
   <input id="title" type="text" class="intro">
   <div class="button-center">
    <button id="intro-button">Proceed</button>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add handler to input and move on parent of input

```
$(function() {
  var elems = $('.intro input').on('keypress', function() {

    if ($(this).val().trim().length > 2) {
      $(this).parent().next('label').addClass('block');
    }


    $('#intro-button').toggle(
      elems.filter(function() {
        return this.value.trim() !== "";
      }).length === elems.length
    )

  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xfbLskhn/3/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`label` event does not exists. You can adjust existing `js` to use `this.firstElementChild`

```
$(function() {
  var elems = $('.intro').on('input', function() {
    if (this.firstElementChild.value.trim().length > 2) {
      $(this).next('label').addClass('block');
    }


    $('#intro-button').toggle(
      elems.filter(function() {
        return this.firstElementChild.value.trim() !== "";
      }).length === elems.length
    )

  });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xfbLskhn/4/